# Conformal map between $D$ and $\{z : |z| < 1 \, \text{and}\,\operatorname{ Im}(z) > i/\sqrt{2}\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Find a conformal (biholomorphic) map between the unit disc $D = \{z : |z|<1\}$ and the domain $U = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \mbox{ and } \operatorname{ Im}(z) > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$.

The first thing I thought was to consider $f_1(z) = z+i/\sqrt{2}$ applied to $U$ (so shifting $U$ so it's contained in the upper-half-plane), and denoting $U_1 = f_1(U)$.  Then consider the maps $1/z$ and $\log(z)$ on $U_1$.  But $1/z$ didn't result in a space that looked familiar.  $\log(z)$ maps $U_1$ to something similar to a horizontal half-strip, but not close enough that I could see what to do.

Edited for typos and clarity.

Comment: You might want to write $z=x+iy$ and $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is  similar to  [Conformal map from a lune to the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59262/79365). The answer given there by GEdgar can hardly be improved upon:

> First apply a linear fractional transformation mapping the two corners (vertices, horns, whatever you call them) to $0$ and $\infty$. The result is a sector. Then apply a power to get a half-plane. Then apply a linear fractional transformation to get a disk.

The "corners" of $U$ are the points $(\pm 1+i)/\sqrt{2}$. The map $z\mapsto \dfrac{z-( 1+i)/\sqrt{2}}{z-(-1+i)/\sqrt{2}}$ transforms $D$ onto a sector with vertex at $0$. One of half-lines bounding the sector contains 
$\dfrac{-i-( 1+i)/\sqrt{2}}{-i-(-1+i)/\sqrt{2}}$, the other contains $\dfrac{i/\sqrt{2}-( 1+i)/\sqrt{2}}{i/\sqrt{2}-(-1+i)/\sqrt{2}}$. Simplify these numbers to identify their arguments, and you'll know what sector you have. The rest (power map, fractional linear transform) is easy.