# Conformal map from $D=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-2|<2 \: \: \text{and} \:\: |z-2i|<2\}$ to the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

How does one find a conformal map from the set 
\begin{equation}
D=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-2|<2 \: \: \text{and} \:\: |z-2i|<2\}
\end{equation}
to the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ such that $1+i$ is mapped to $0$?

I don't know how to start. I drew the picture, it's just the intersection of two circles. But that's it. Can someone help me how to solve such problems? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints** Recall that a linear fractional transformation maps circles (including lines, which are circles through $\infty$) to circles. So, if you find a l.f.t. $f$ that maps one of the intersection points to $0$ and the other to $\infty$, then $f$ maps the two boundary arcs to rays from the origin and hence $D$ to a sector.

Comment: Okay thank you, I first have to rotate it $45$ degrees clockwise? And then apply the l.f.t. $z/(z-2\sqrt{2})$ or am I totaly wrong? And how does the sector look like exactly?

Comment: As is usually the case with problems for constructing conformal maps, you have some measure of freedom in your choices, and the method you describe is efficient. Personally, I would first apply the l.f.t. $z \mapsto -\frac{z}{z - (2 + 2i)}$, which (since the arcs comprising $\partial D$ intersect at a right angle) maps $D$ to a quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this type of exercise is already discussed in this post

[Conformal map from a lune to the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59262/conformal-map-from-a-lune-to-the-unit-disc-in-mathbbc?rq=1)