# Conceptual Question

Tags: calculus, linear-transformations, mobius-transformation, potential-theory, linear-fractional-transformation

Hi guys I am a engineering student(in my 4th semester). I was having trouble with the following question. Kindly tell me how to approach and solve this question.
Also please tell me some nice online resources that i can use to study this topic because I think I am weak in it currently.
The question is: **Find a suitable linear fractional transformation to study potential for a region (in the form of lense) common between two circles of radius 1 centered at 1 and i and kept at constant potential Φ = 1 and Φ = 0, respectively.**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59262/1257